# django-filters - field_labels not working for OrderingFilter

Tags: django, django-filter

There is a model:

```
class Calendar(models.Model):
    ...
    vendor_code = models.TextField()
    ...
```

FilterSet class:

```
from django_filters import OrderingFilter
from django_filters.rest_framework import FilterSet, DjangoFilterBackend

class CalendarFilter(FilterSet):

    ordering = OrderingFilter(
        fields=(
            ('vendor_code', 'vendor_code'),
        ),
        field_labels={
            'vendor_code': 'Vendor code',
        }
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Calendar
        fields = ['vendor_code']
```

The view:

```
class CalendarsView(mixins.ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    ...
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = CalendarFilter
```

I expected that if define `field_labels` param the label `Vendor code` would appear in swagger but there is only `ordering` without any description:

[image]

I need this in order to frontend developers could see them.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`OrderingFilter` is used in View like this:

```
class CalendarsView(mixins.ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    ...
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter,filters.OrderingFilter]
    filter_class = CalendarFilter
    filter_backends = [filters.OrderingFilter]
```

and in `CalendarFilter` used field:

```
class CalendarFilter(FilterSet):
    vendor_code = filters.CharFilter(field_name='vendor_code', lookup_expr='icontains', label='vendor_code')
```

Comment: It's not working

Comment: Does your config OK?

Comment: ```    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter]
    filter_class = ProductFilter
```

Comment: see the filter_backends